# UICollectionViewCell will not be selected when UIImageView has been touched

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

1. I have a UICollectionViewController, and I have built a Reusable UICollectionViewCell in storyboard. Cell has only an UIImageView( my custom UIImageView -- BorderedImageView).I have set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true` and I added a `tap gesture` to the image view.
2. I clicked UIImageView, I wondering which cell( IndexPath ) was being clicked. But there was no cell being selected( I mean that `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method never be invoked ) after I clicked image view.

`How can I deal with this issue? How can I know the IndexPath I had clicked?`

Comment: set imageview set user interaction enable and what do you mean by no cell being selected

Comment: I have set `userInteractionEnabled = true`.  I mean that `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method never be invoked.

Comment: make sure your imageview and collectionview has userInteractionEnabled = true and check you have bind delegate and  dataSource to collection view

Comment: I am sure that I had set these properties correctly. But `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` never be invoked.